# How to load a .phtml page content in a popup in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, frontend, image, modal-popup

I need to load a .phtml content on a popup.

```
 <div>
        <a href="#" id="click-me">Click Me</a>
    </div>

    <div id="popup-mpdal" style="display:none;">
        <h1> Hi I'm here.... </h1>

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Elem‌​ent\Template")->setT‌​emplate("Namespace_Customtab::new.phtml"‌​)->toHtml();?>
    </div>

    <script>
        require(
            [
                'jquery',
                'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
            ],

            function(
                $,
                modal
            ) {
                var options = {
                    type: 'popup',
                    responsive: true,
                    innerScroll: true,
                    title: 'popup mpdal title',
                    buttons: [{
                        text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                        class: '',
                        click: function () {
                            this.closeModal();
                        }
                    }]
                };

                var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal'));
                $("#click-me").on('click',function(){
                    $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");
                });

            }
        );
    </script>
```

This is my code. How to load another phtml content instead of that div ? Please help me In find a solution.

custom file path: app/code/Namespace/Customtab/view/frontend/templates/product/view/new.phtml

Comment: Whats the issue have you faced? I m here content is not display after click on button?

Comment: When i click on the Click me button, it displays a popup with the Hi i'm here content. But instead of that i need to display another phtml page content. for that what i need to do?

Comment: Try this code : <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml")->toHtml();?>

Comment: which phtml template want to define in popup?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya a custom phtml

Comment: @AmritPalSingh how i  implement that in popup script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer to load phtml file:

```
<div id="popup-mpdal" style="display:none;">
    <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Namespace_Customtab::image.phtml')) ?>
</div>
```

By this, we can popup the custom phtml page.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below code,

if your phtml file contains **any Custom Block** then replace `Magento\Framework\View\Elem‌​ent\Template` with `your custom block path`.

```
<div id="popup-mpdal" style="display:none;">
    <h1> Hi I'm here.... </h1>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Elem‌​ent\Template")->setT‌​emplate("Namespace_Customtab::product/view/new.phtml"‌​)->toHtml();?>
</div>
```

Comment: not have any block, so i pasted like this <div id="popup-mpdal" style="display:none;">
      <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Elem‌​ent\Template")->setT‌​emplate("Namesapce_Customtab::new.phtml"‌​)->toHtml();?>
</div>   but it shows a syntax error :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento214/app/code/Namesapce/Customtab/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml on line 30

Comment: is your module name "Namesap‌​ce_Customtab:?

Comment: yes.. Anything wrong?

Comment: i think it should be Namespace not Namsapce, right you typomistake

Comment: its a typomistake when i wrote here, in code the module name s correct

Comment: please add your code in questions.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: again it shows that same error :(  :( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento214/app/code/Namespace/Customtab/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml on line 46

Comment: what is product/view/galle‌​ry.phtml we havent defined this file in your module.

Comment: Its the file where i pasted this popup code.

Comment: please show full code of gallery.phtml file

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
  `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Namespace_Module::name_of_phtml.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>`
```